# Ruby Mechanize and changing URL after a login

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I have a Mechanize script that currently goes to a login form and properly logs a user in. I'm seeing plenty of documentation to follow links, but I'd like to go to an ad-hoc page that isn't linked on the main page after I login. The page requires authentication and that's why I force the login first. Is there a way to change to another URL (that's still part of the same site) with Ruby's Mechanize gem and have it retain all of the cookies from the login? I looked up methods such as `link_with` but that's to follow a link on the current page. I'd like to go to a different url within the same website.

Comment: Yes, every subsequent request will automatically send the cookies that have already been set.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to make a subsequent `get` call after your initial transaction is complete.

```
client = Mechanize.new
client.get('http://example.com/login') do
    # handle login
end
client.get('http://example.com/something-else') do
    # another action
end
```